# Uniform error of approximating the Heaviside function by a partial sum of its Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series, approximation

Suppose $f(x)=H(x-.5)$ where H = Heaviside function on $0<x<1$ is approximated by the first five nonzero terms of its Fourier sine series.  Compute the uniform error (i.e maximum error, max p(x) for all $0<x<1$) in this approximation

I know how to do (absolute) pointwise error $p(x)=|f(x)-S_n(x)|$ where $S_n(x)$ is the Fourier sine series, but I have no notes on how to do uniform error.

Comment: Do the pointwise error for all points, then find the maximum of that error function.

Comment: How do I do it for all points? There is an infinite amount of points

Comment: You said you knew how to do it pointwise. The result will be some function of the point where you are calculating the error. You want to figure out where that function will be maximum.

Comment: Are you sure you're expected to do this by hand? I imagine this kind of task outsourced to a computer.